# Too many DAD collisions with CentOS7 in virtualbox

Tags: ipv6, virtualbox

I'm tring to install an IPv6 Server with centOS7.

I just want to add a static IP 1000::206/64 on this interface.
Here's the configuation of /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3

    `TYPE=Ethernet
    PROXY_METHOD=none
    BROWSER_ONLY=no
    BOOTPROTO=dhcp
    DEFROUTE=yes
    IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
    IPV6INIT=yes
    IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
    IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
    IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
    IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
    NAME=enp0s3
    UUID=0bfd1001-00e4-4aca-8738-789626fe649a
    DEVICE=enp0s3
    ONBOOT=yes
    IPV6ADDR=1000::206/64
    IPV6_PEERROUTES=no`

After rebooting and check logs by journalctl, it says

`device (enp0s3): linklocal6: failed to generate an address: Too many DAD collisions`

Run command:

    `ip -6 a`

It seems that all IPv6 address is on state "tentative"

`1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 1000::206/64 scope global tentative dadfailed
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::67a3:6066:8dd:128f/64 scope link tentative dadfailed
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::79f7:2dc9:2a7e:1f81/64 scope link tentative dadfailed
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::389b:a8f:3d5a:8f46/64 scope link tentative dadfailed
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`

There are 3 link-local with prefix `fe80`. journalctl shows log:

`device (enp0s3): ipv6: duplicate address check failed for the fe80::389b:a8f:3d5a:8f46/64 lft forever pref forever lifetime 2-0[4294967295,4294967295] dev 2 flags tentative,permanent,0x8 src kernel address
device (enp0s3): ipv6: duplicate address check failed for the fe80::79f7:2dc9:2a7e:1f81/64 lft forever pref forever lifetime 3-0[4294967295,4294967295] dev 2 flags tentative,permanent,0x8 src kernel address
device (enp0s3): ipv6: duplicate address check failed for the fe80::67a3:6066:8dd:128f/64 lft forever pref forever lifetime 3-0[4294967295,4294967295] dev 2 flags tentative,permanent,0x8 src kernel address`

So NetworkManager tried 3 times for new local-link address but failed.

There are only 2 element in this network. One is this centos7 and the other is the host machine of virtual box. The host machine is Windows 7 and connected to a cisco switch with cable. No other computer connected to this switch.

I tried to install Ubuntu or Archlinux or CentOS6 with virtual box, there's no problem.
I also tried centos7 + vmware, also worked well.
Only the CentOS7 and virtualbox.
I did nothing but only modify the configuation ifcfg-enp0s3.

BTW, IPv4 with DHCP or fixed IP on enp0s3 works well.

Answer (score 0):

Replace virtual box with old version 4.30, problem gone.

Latest CentOS 7 is released at Aug, 2017, Virtual Box v5.2 released at Jan,2018. There may be some compatibility issues, I guess.